# Как отправить сообщение в тему (форум, topic) в чате, Telethon?

Tags: бот, события, telethon

Всем добра!

Приходит event в:

```
@client.on(events.NewMessage())
async def new_message(event: events):
    pass
```

В чате есть три топика: "Один", "Два" и "#Главный". Допустим, сообщение написано в топике "Один", как мне отправить ответ в него же?

Если использовать

```
event.respond("Сообщение")
```

..., то оно попадает в "#Главный". Да и вообще сообщение event.respond() из любой темы отправляет в главный.

Смотрел содержимое event, не нашёл там данных о теме чата. Прошу помощи :)

Answer (score 0):

UPD
Нашёл, вот так:

```
group_name = -100XXXXXXXXX
topic_id = YYYY
await client.send_message(group_name, message, reply_to=topic_id)
```

topic_id можно узнать, скопировав урл любого сообщения в самом топике (ПКМ на пост -> копировать URL сообщения): https://t.me/c/XXXXXXXXX/YYYY/ZZZZ, где:
XXXXXXXXX - chat_id
YYYY - topic_id
ZZZZ - message_id

=-=-=-=-=--=-=

```
@client.on(events.NewMessage())
async def handler(event):
    await event.reply("Сообщение")
```

Ответит в том же топике, в котором было написано сообщение. Но вот как без ответа послать в определённый топик сообщение, я так и не разобрался пока что

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! если у вас появился новый вопрос, задайте его, пожалуйста, с помощью кнопки «[задать вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)» в правом верхнем углу страницы; если нужно указать контекст, дайте ссылку на этот вопрос.